# Reliably scraping stock price tables

Tags: javascript, python, r, selenium, web-scraping

**The Problem:**

My goal is to automate scraping a table with currency prices from this website [stock prices](https://iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=120&date=2016-12-19-19-0). As the stock broker *doesn't provide API*, I'm forced to find work arounds.

I have already searched for applications for this purpose in order to avoid reinventing the wheel and wasting time/money, but unfortunately I didn't find a single one, which would work with this website.

**What I've tried:**

1. `R` and [`rvest`](https://github.com/hadley/rvest)

R is known for its simplicity and straight forward use. Lets look at the code which is basically a copy-paste example from a texbook:

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=120&date=2016-12-19-19-0"
population <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mCSB_3_container"]/table') %>%
  html_table()
population
population <- population[[1]]

head(population)
```

Getting an empty table.

2. `JavaScript` and [`casperJS`](http://casperjs.org/)

This option is by far the best, I'm actually able to extract the data, but it is very slow and eventually crashes with a "memory exhausted" error:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  logLevel:'debug',
  verbose:true,
  loadImages: false,
  loadPlugins: false,
  webSecurityEnabled: false,
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
});

var url = 'https://eu.iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=60&date=2016-12-19-21-0';
var length;
var fs = require('fs');
var sep = ';';
//var count = 0;
casper.start(url);

//date
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var hh = today.getHours();  
var fff = today.getMilliseconds();  
var MM = today.getMinutes();

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 


var today = yyyy +'_'+mm + '_' +dd + '_'+ hh +'_'+ MM +'_'+ fff;
casper.echo(today);

function getCellContent(row, cell) {
    cellText = casper.evaluate(function(row, cell) {
        return document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')[row].childNodes[cell].innerText.trim();
    }, row, cell);
    return cellText;
}

function moveNext()
{
    var rows = casper.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
    });
    length = rows.length;
    this.echo("table length: " + length);
};

//get 3 tables
for (var mins = 0; mins < 3; mins++)
{ 

    url = 'https://eu.iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=60&date=2016-12-19-21-' + mins;

    casper.echo(url);
    casper.thenOpen(url);
     casper.then(function() {
        this.waitForSelector('#mCSB_3_container table tbody tr');
    }); 

    casper.then(moveNext);

    casper.then(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        //this.echo("Date: " + getCellContent(i, 0));
        //this.echo("Bid: " + getCellContent(i, 1));
        //this.echo("Ask: " + getCellContent(i, 2));
        //this.echo("Quotes: " + getCellContent(i, 4));

        fs.write('prices_'+today+'.csv', getCellContent(i, 0) + sep + getCellContent(i, 1) + sep + getCellContent(i, 2) + sep + getCellContent(i, 4) + "\n", "a");
    }
    });  


}

casper.run(); 
this.echo("finished with processing");
```

3. `JavaScipt` and [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/)

With this option I'm only getting a single table:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('https://iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=120&date=2016-12-19-19-0', function(status) {

  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');

  });
});
```

4. `Python` and [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Getting an empty table as a result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen


url = "https://iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=120&date=2016-12-19-19-0"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "lxml")

table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={ "class" : "quotes-table-result"})
print("table length is: "+ str(len(table)))
```

5. [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org)

Tried with the "Scrapy Shell" but got an empty table as a result.

6. [`Pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and it's [`read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

With `pandas` I've got the following error:

> ValueError: No tables found matching pattern '.+'

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

f_states = pd.read_html("https://iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=120&date=2016-12-19-19-0")
print f_states
```

**The Questions:**

1. Could you please explain why I'm getting empty tables while trying different different web-scraping and HTML parsing tools?
2. What would be the most reliable way to approach web-scraping of this particular stock price web-site?

Note: it might be the site is trying to prevent web-scraping, I've studied [`robots.txt`](https://iqoption.com/robots.txt), but it looks like there are only browser-support specific and google-bot specific instructions.

Comment: Try python with `selenium` Ref: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Comment: Try python with Scrapy+splash. @Prabhakar Selenium is good but too slow.

Comment: Also python + pandas'  `read_html` is nice. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: @parik: there is not even  an installation manual available of splash for windows. By excident I've googled command which goes like '>pip install scrapy-splash'. Fine, it installs splash, but how to run this bloody thing which is middleware afterall (whatever that means). Guys, this is too complicated. But there is something wrong with all of this stuff - how the hell on earth can not be such a bloody trivial task, like like scraping a table,  simply  achieved by installing an app and writing less than 10 lines of code? So much about easy-to-use, straightfoward and high-level tools.

Comment: @UnfriendlyNeighbour sometimes websites adopt anti-scraping techniques. I tried a few times and it appears that when Beutifulsoup or read_html download the source code it arrives without the table with the actual data, so the scripts doesn't match any table.

Comment: @UnfriendlyNeighbour for installing splash on windows, you can use Docker :)

Comment: What about [Google Sheets `GOOGLEFINANCE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) function that fetches current or historical information from Google Finance?

Comment: `GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG","price",TODAY()-30,TODAY())` or `GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")`

Answer (score 6):

The main problem is that this particular site is *quite dynamic* - loading the tables is done asynchronously with additional XHR requests which your browser would make.

All the approaches except for the ones using the actual browser (`casperJS` or `PhantomJS`) would fail since they would only download *the initial HTML page* without all the dynamic parts. In other words, `rvest` or `urllib2` are not browsers and they don't have JavaScript engines built-in.

Now, with that said, since there is no public API available for this resource, you basically have two general options, let's call it "Low-level" and "High-level":

1. "Low-level". Using the browser developer tools, inspect how the tables are loaded and simulate the same requests in your code - using, for example, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).
2. "High-level". Actually *automate a real browser* with, for example, [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). This option is similar to your `casperJS` and `phantomJS` approaches, but you have to account for certain things like "waiting for elements to be loaded" - giving a browser time to load the page and the tables.

Let's focus on the second approach. Install `selenium` via `pip`:

```
pip install selenium
```

Let's use Chrome (you can also use `Firefox` or `PhantomJS` or others as well). Assuming you have the actual browser installed, download latest [`chromedriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for Windows. Go through the [Getting Started](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) page and make sure you have it working.

Then, let's load your webpage, wait for the tables to be loaded (the waiting is done via [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and a set of Expected Conditions). Then, we'll get the page source and pass it to `pandas` for further parsing and data extraction (we could have done it via `selenium` as well - locate elements and get their texts, but this would be slow - remember your `casperJS` approach):

```
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://iqoption.com/en/historical-financial-quotes?active_id=1&tz_offset=120&date=2016-12-19-19-0"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

# wait for a table to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mCSB_3_container table tbody tr")))

# read the page source and pass it to "pandas"
dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

# close the browser - we don't need it anymore, it's job is done
driver.close()

print(dfs)  # dfs is a list of DataFrame instances
```

Note that you don't have to do the HTML parsing and data extraction with `pandas` - once you have the HTML source in the `driver.page_source`, you've done the most complicated part. Then, you can use whichever tool you are comfortable with - popular options are `BeautifulSoup` or [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). The latter would be a good choice from the performance perspective.

---

As a side note, when doing web-scraping, you should always try to be a good web-scraping citizen and stay on the legal side - comply to the "Terms of Use" of a service, respect the "robots.txt" rules, do not hit the site too often and/or identify yourself either by providing a specific "User-Agent" header or contacting the resource owners or maintainers about the best ways to get to the desired data. Related resources:

- [Web scraping etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette)
- [How to be a good citizen when crawling web sites?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91760/how-to-be-a-good-citizen-when-crawling-web-sites)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you simply use quantmod for this?

```
install.packages('quantmod')
```

Then...

```
> getSymbols("YHOO",src="google") # from google finance 
[1] "YHOO" 
> getSymbols("GOOG",src="yahoo") # from yahoo finance 
[1] "GOOG" 
> getSymbols("DEXJPUS",src="FRED") # FX rates from FRED 
[1] "DEXJPUS" 
> getSymbols("XPT/USD",src="Oanda") # Platinum from Oanda 
[1] "XPTUSD"
```

Each call results in the data being loaded directly into your workspace, with the name of the object returned from the call. Sort of handy, but it gets better...

```
> # Specify lookup parameters, and save for future sessions. 
> 
> setSymbolLookup(YHOO='google',GOOG='yahoo') 
> setSymbolLookup(DEXJPUS='FRED') 
> setSymbolLookup(XPTUSD=list(name="XPT/USD",src="oanda")) 
> saveSymbolLookup(file="mysymbols.rda") 
> # new sessions call loadSymbolLookup(file="mysymbols.rda") 
> 
> getSymbols(c("YHOO","GOOG","DEXJPUS","XPTUSD")) 
[1] "YHOO" "GOOG" "DEXJPUS" "XPTUSD"
```

See this link for all details.

http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/#data